# Java - calculate displacement between two frames of an image

Tags: java, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I have a webcam mounted on my car capturing the outside environment. So, as the vehicle keeps moving forward, the objects in the frame move from left to right. i want to check whether two consecutive frames captured by the webcam are the same. if they are not same, i want to know how much the second frame has been displaced from the first frame ? please suggest me how to calculate this displacement ? I am using Java. suggest me a suitable solution .

Thanks!

Comment: question is too abstract

Comment: Generalized displacement of two points in time can have contributions from rigid body translations, rotations, and deformations or distortions.  You'd have to ID the coordinates of each point in the original frame at the beginning and end of the time step.

Comment: it's called: optical flow

Comment: @berak nailed it.  Take a look at motion estimation algorithms.  Optical Flow is one approach, but you can also look at block matching algorithms too that are commonly used in video compression standards (MPEG, H.264, etc.).

Comment: it would need *calibrated stereo* to do proper displacement, not consecutive frames from a single cam.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable inputs. Adding more details.. the frame is of 50x480 resolution. and I would like to project the colours captured in the frame to an LED strip having 32 LEDs. That is, i take a block of 50x15 and give a corresponding colour representation to each of the LED. this way, i would like to do for video stream. for this, will it be sufficient if i try to match the first block pf pixels (50x15) of frame 1 to the next frame ? hope u get the funda. expecting ur suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy part is testing if the entire image is the same; just check all pixels, and if they match, it's all good.

The problem though is that two frames are very unlikely to match, since webcams tend to have a lot of pixel noise. This would mean you'd need a more sophisticated algorithm to match frames ignoring the noise.

It'll be even harder to determine how much the frames have moved, if the background is anything more than a simple, easily recognizable pattern. That being said, there are ways to do it.

One common strategy in pixel analysis is to sample small groups of pixels, say, a few 4x4 squares of them from the first image. Then, you can search the second image for 4x4 groups similar to the ones you had before. If enough pixels match from the groups, then you can be reasonably assured that you've found the offset of the second  image.

I hope this helps!